# Will this motor controller take more motors?

Tags: transistors, current, dc-motor

## If I was to connect two motors in parallel instead of just the one motor it currently has on each H-Bridge,, would the transistors on the motor controller blow?

I have [this](http://www.lpilsley.co.uk/cybot/driver.htm) motor controller - here is a schematic & table as well:
[image: schematic]

[image: arrow]The lowest pin on the connector is pin 7  --------  The lowest on this connector is pin 1   [image: arrow]

[image: table]

I am controlling this using my Raspberry Pi, connected to the first 4 pins and last pin of the 7 pin socket - this is not relevant as such, but this outputs 3V3, and controls the H-Bridge.

An individual motor draws less than 0.1A at 6VDC, but on startup and stop can draw up 0.48A *These measurements are from a multimeter, which will only take an average anyway*.

Each motor has one of these already attached as well: 
[image]

Here are the transistors:

Q7 - Q10 are 2SC3279 - NPN, can take 2Amps DC, 5Amps 1/100th  of a second

Q11 - Q14 are 2SA1300 - PNP, can -2A DC, -5A also for 1/100th  of a second

For more info on the controller see [here](http://www.lpilsley.co.uk/cybot/driver.htm)

Here are some data sheets of the relevant transistors:
[2SC3270](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/30173/TOSHIBA/2SC3279.html)
[2SA1300](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/214583/TOSHIBA/2SA1300.html)

Comment: I expect that there is an error in the Maximum Ratings table - a transistor having 2 mA max collector current wouldn't be very useful.  The Electrical Characteristics table gives Hfe for 4 Amp, and Vce-sat at 2 amps which seem more reasonable for this application, and is a reasonable match for the NPN rating.

Comment: If found [this](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/214583/TOSHIBA/2SA1300.html) datasheet which seems 10 years updated compared to the original one I referenced to *([this](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/29965/TOSHIBA/2SA1300.html) one)*. I shall  update my question, @Peter

Comment: I don't get it: The motor controller you have described already supports two motors, and has separate connections for each. So why would you need to parallel the motors? Other than that, yes, you certainly can wire up two motors in parallel, or even more, so long as the total starting current is within the capabilities of the drive transistors and the supply.

Comment: No, instead of the **two** motors it currently powers, I want to run **four** - two controlled by one H-Bridge, two by the other H-bridge. The thing is, the peak current I get on my multi-meter from one motor starting is 0.48A *(which is an average, so presumably at least a third smaller than the actual peak)*, so putting two in parrallel may double it, so starting the motors may blow the H-Bridge... @AnindoGhosh

Comment: @wilf So do you know what the peak current capacity of each H-bridge is? Also, your assumption about the spike current being "*at least a third smaller than the actual peak*" is invalid: The start current is a spike, so depending on the time constant of the multimeter's current sensor, and the stiction / load torque on the motor, the reading could be marginally smaller or much much smaller. To alleviate this somewhat, add higher capacitance across the motors: Instead of the tan colored itty bitty 0.1 uF (104) capacitors you have on the motors, shove in a 10 uF (non-polarized) capacitor there.

Comment: Shall I keep the O.1uF for the smaller spikes? *(as far as I can remember, using a range of capacitors is a good idea)*. Then I just need to find a non-polarized capacitor. I did not get much for the stall current when I tested the motor, I shall try and get around to testing the start, stall, and stop currents of **two** motors as well. Thanks for the help @AnindoGhosh

Comment: @wilf No harm keeping the existing cap in place. To measure shall current, just block the motor from rotating, then drive it with perhaps one third the nominal voltage. Multiply the resultant measured current by 3 for a reasonable if very rough approximation.

Comment: Thanks @AnindoGhosh , I just found the stall current is too big...

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't take any more motors [image: sad].

Just ran a few tests for **two** motors connected in parallel to the same power supply as would be used by the controller. - here are the results:

- **Measured start current:** 0.88A at  circa 4.9V
- **Measured running current:** Anything between 0.2A and 0.6A, also circa 4.9V
- **Measured STALL current**: Generally above 1.8A, voltage can drop to around 3V for one or both motors stalling, **which also results in a current of around 2.2A**, which is too big for the motor controller to handle...

Just have to find another one, I guess...